# No persister for: NHibernate.Examples.QuickStart.User

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, nhibernate

Question: I have an annoying problem with nhibernate.
The problem is I cannot get any example I find on the web to work...
I've now tried for two days...

The first problem was it wouldn't read the config file, so I had to move it into app.config / web.config.

The second problem is that whatever I do, I always get an error:
**No persister for: NHibernate.Examples.QuickStart.User**

I've searched google and I did change the mapping to embeded ressource, and I did add the mapping to the config file, but nothing helps...

The example is from this page: 
https://www.hibernate.org/362.html

I've uploaded my Visual Studio 2005 project to
http://verzend.be/exchange/NhibernateCrap.rar

Does anybody know what I do wrong ?

Comment: What version of NH are you using? Are you sure the example is for the same version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's everything I had to fix to get your code working:

- `Configuration.LoadMappingDocument` only validates the mapping, but does not add it to the configuration, i.e. it works as documented. It should probably have a better name (like `ValidateMapping` or something). Use `AddFile`, `AddDocument` or similar instead, though I recommend using `AddAssembly` and having the mapping embedded as a resource;
- In the mapping when you write `<class name="NHibernate.Examples.QuickStart.User, NHibernate.Examples"` the part after the comma is the assembly name. It should be `<class name="NHibernate.Examples.QuickStart.User, NHibernateCrap"`, or you should change the assembly name (I'd recommend that);
- I had to change the mapping XML namespace to the 2.2 one: `<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">`
- Finally, because NHibernate lazy-loads by default, you have to make all properties virtual or disable lazy loading (not recommended). The example is actually wrong in this aspect;

For further learning I recommend you read Gabriel Schenker's [NHibernate tutorials](https://web.archive.org/web/20090831053827/http://blogs.hibernatingrhinos.com/nhibernate/archive/2008/04/01/your-first-nhibernate-based-application.aspx).

Comment: ah, suspected the mapping file, but didn't know what was wrong.
Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Clean up your namespace and assembly names and it will probably work. Please don't ask others to find your bug when your bug exists because the code is a mess.

Comment: In that case: Personally I started with NHibernate with the video tutorials of summerofnhibernate.com. At the time, FluentNhiberante did not exist. Now I would use the unit tests of the FluentNhibernate sourcecode as examples for the mapping.

Comment: Well, it's not my code, it's the examples of other people. I've started making changes, and that did correct some to many errors, but still I couldn't get even one example to work... With all the time that took me (but without any useful result), I'd probably be better of writing my own wrapper.